# Track ActivityStateRecord using Activity type

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

How to track the ActivityStateRecord using the activity type in the tracking profile ActivityStateQuery.
I am able to track the activity using the Display name but there is not any property for the Activity type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Tracking Profile to filter on Activity type using an ActivityStateQuery.

ActivityStateQuery filters on ActivityName, Arguments, QueryAnnotations, States and Variables.

You can filter in code.  e.g. Use a TrackingParticipant to subscribe to the ActivityStateRecord and then filter on the result.
e.g.

```
class WorkflowTracking : TrackingParticipant
{
    protected override void Track(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
       ActivityStateRecord activityStateRecord = record as ActivityStateRecord;

       if (activityStateRecord != null)
       {
          while(activityStateRecord.Activity.TypeName == "Main.Workflows.Components.DummyItem")
          {
             using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"c:\temp\tracking.txt"))
             {
                 writer.WriteLine(activityStateRecord.ToString());
                 writer.WriteLine();
                 writer.Close();
             }
          }
       }
   }
}
```